# Connecting failure to Azure Ubuntu Server via Remote Desktop

Tags: ubuntu, azure, rdp, graphical-user-interface

I cannot connect to my Ubuntu Server via RDP. SSH works properly. I have installed ubuntu-dekstop and xrdp as it is well described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496915/how-can-i-connect-to-ubunto-at-azure/23497082#23497082

Both of them seemed to be succeeded.
I have also created a TCP endpoint for the Ubuntu in Azure with the port 3389.

The RDP client simply cannot reach the server. I have tried to connect from 3 different machines (and all of them can connect to other servers via RDP), and this is now the second installed Ubuntu server in Azure which does not work.

What can cause this issue?